# Setting different values for one exported variable

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to use different languages for users on my website without using i18n.
Currently I am having issues on setting setting one variable with different values coming from two different files. Reason is that exported variable need to be set with a value in the beginning and ideally cannot be changed after. Is there a way to transform it into an conditional variable that can be exported after?

Here is my code example:

english.js (file)

```
var lang_eng = {
    "administration": {
        "building": "Administration of Building",
        "information": "Inoformation",
        "regsiterd_user": "Registered user: ",
        "actived_user": "Activated user: ",
        "available_rolls": "Available roles: ",
        "administrator": "Administrator: "
}
```

german.js (file)

```
export var lang_de = {
    "user_administration": {
        "building": "Administration of Building",
        "information": "Inofrmationen",
        "regsiterd_user": "Registrierte Benutzer: ",
        "actived_user": "Aktivierte Benutzer: ",
        "available_rolls": "Verfügbare Rollen: ",
        "administrators": "Administratoren: "

    }
```

I want to use the third HTML file to set the different languages in a dropdown Botton

At the moment I can only change the language manually with the third exported variable "languageSelector" which is defined as a Hook that derive the keys from the respective language files in different pages.

`export var languageSelector = lang_de` for German
or
`export languageSelector = lang_eng` for English

Do you have any idea on how to use a local Storage for that?

Really thanks al to in advance for your help.

Comment: It would be simpler if you just keep English and German strings in the same object, and use the selected language as the key to extract the appropriate language sub-object. Also, you don't need to put quotes on the object keys in JavaScript, it is only needed in JSON.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. This was only an example on how I structured the object as I have more strings (each over 100) within the different languages, so I thought I would make sense to separate see. But yes, I will remove the quotes